# How do I insert items into an NSTableView when I click a button?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, nstableview

I need a simple ListBox where I can just insert many items whenever I like. I've been told to use a NSTableView, but the tutorials I have found are all overkill for this scenario and since I am new to OS X development, it's also very difficult to follow along when all I want is something *simple*, first.

How do I insert a bunch of items *when I click a button*? All of the tutorials seem to rely on some underlying datasource - but for some reason there don't exist any tutorials for those occasions where we're not collecting anything from a database, or an XML file.

---

In C# for example, I can do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int 1 = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
    }
}
```

So that's basically all I am trying to do right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a simple way using the Cocoa bindings which can be achieved using a array controller and a array.

The apple developer docs has this tutorial explaining the same,
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html